# Increasing sequence by derivative?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

I prove that f is an increasing function like that:

$\exists d. (0 < d) \wedge \forall p. (0 < p \wedge p < d) 
\Rightarrow  (f(x) < f (x + p))$

Now, I would like to prove that the sequence f is also increasing.
I know that this seems to be obvious, but I need the math proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** (needs to be filled in)

Starting from $x$ you can by taking $p=d/2$ get to anything of the form $x+k*d/2$, and since $f(x)<f(x+p)$ for all $p<d$ the sequence of intervals 
$$[x,x+d/2], [x+d/2,x+2\cdot(d/2], \cdots$$
may be joined up to conclude that if $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y).$ That is, if $y$ is not initially within $d$ of $x$ the relation follows by transitivity.

For example $f(x)<f(x+d/2)$ and $f(x+d/2)<f(x+2\cdot(d/2)$ implies that also $f(x)<f(x+2\cdot(d/2)0$, and similarly by more iterations $f(x)<f(x+k\cdot(d/2))$

Then after enough iterations to arrive just before $y$ you can do one more from there to $y$ itself to finish.

ANOTHER WAY: Given $x<y$ choose some -positive integer $n$ for which $\alpha=(y-x)/n<d$. Then apply $f(x)<f(x+\alpha)$ a total of $n$ times, increasing the input by $\alpha$ each time, and use transitivity of $<$ to conclude $f(x)<f(y).$